# Set Data Labels as values from Range in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, charts, format

I am trying to set my Data Labels equal to custom values. However, they do not appear. I have clearly defined the range in which they might appear and do not know why they don't.

```
Dim names As Range
Set names = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown))

Set mypts = mysrs.Points

mypts(mypts.count).ApplyDataLabels

With mypts(mypts.count).DataLabel
    .ShowSeriesName = False
    .ShowCategoryName = False
    .ShowValue = False
    ' optional parameters
    .Position = xlLabelPositionAbove
    .Font.name = "Helvetica"
    .Font.Size = 10
    .Font.Bold = False
End With

For Each pt In mypts
    k = k + 1
    pt.DataLabel.Text = names.Cells(k, 1).Text
Next
```

Could I pass through the names as an array?

Comment: Here's how you could do it with formulas instead of vba https://peltiertech.com/apply-custom-data-labels-to-charted-points/

Comment: Kinda needs to be VBA.

Comment: did you mean for this line to be `names.Cells(k, 1).Tex`t  to match the variable that you increment? `k = k + 1`

Comment: I changed that in my code, but nothing updates.

Comment: Does it change the labels if, for testing, you replace it with `pt.DataLabel.Text = "hi"`

Comment: No. It doesn't change it to "hi" as suggested. Therefore I have incorrect code.

Comment: I think I remember something about having to first 'turn on' data labels, let me look around

Comment: Does that `.ApplyDataLabels` allow that to work for you?

Comment: It is something that I had for another block of code when I was interested in showing Series Names. But I simply want to label each point of a series based on a value in a range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 2 issues with your code. You are applying the label formating only to the last point. Second you did not write *.HasDataLabel=True*.Try the following code (Note I am assuming you already defined *mysrs* correctly)

```
Dim names As Range
Set names = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown)

Set mypts = mysrs.Points

'mypts(mypts.Count).ApplyDataLabels

For k = 1 To mypts.Count

    mypts(k).HasDataLabel = True
    mypts(k).DataLabel.Text = names.Cells(k, 1).Text

    With mypts(k).DataLabel
    .ShowSeriesName = False
    .ShowCategoryName = False
    .ShowValue = False
    ' optional parameters
    .Position = xlLabelPositionAbove
    .Font.Name = "Helvetica"
    .Font.Size = 10
    .Font.Bold = False

    End With

Next k
```

Hope This helps